# Automatic Manipulation of experimental data and plotting

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, fitting

I have experimental data which looks like this
[image]

In the high positive and negative x-axis regions, my data is always linear, I want to extract the slope of data in these regions, take average and subtract that linear slope from this experimental data.

```
BMoment = {-0.0000331, -0.0000354, -0.0000334, -0.0000315, -0.0000291, \
-0.0000269, -0.0000251, -0.0000234, -0.0000211, -0.0000189, \
-0.0000173, -0.0000152, -0.0000131, -0.0000114, -9.51*10^-6, \
-9.51*10^-6, -5.75*10^-6, -3.96*10^-6, -2.5*10^-6, -6.15*10^-7, 
 1.29*10^-6, 3.28*10^-6, 4.95*10^-6, 6.9*10^-6, 
 8.81*10^-6, 0.0000107, 0.000012, 0.0000139, 0.0000156, 0.0000172, \
0.0000186, 0.0000199, 0.0000214, 0.0000229, 0.000024, 0.0000259, \
0.0000271, 0.0000284, 0.0000294, 0.0000302, 0.0000314, 0.0000322, \
0.0000331, 0.0000334, 0.0000332, 0.0000331, 0.0000321, 0.0000303, \
0.0000276, "", 
 7.27*10^-6, -8.61*10^-6, -0.000013, -0.0000166, -0.0000189, \
-0.0000208, -0.0000221, -0.0000229, -0.0000236, -0.0000241, \
-0.0000242, -0.0000242, "", -0.0000238, -0.0000224, -0.0000214, \
-0.0000205, -0.0000192, -0.000018, -0.0000168, -0.0000154, \
-0.0000137, -0.0000125, -0.0000109, -9.51*10^-6, -7.62*10^-6, \
-6.17*10^-6, -4.43*10^-6, -2.91*10^-6, -1.1*10^-6, 4.78*10^-7, 
 2.29*10^-6, 3.93*10^-6, 5.83*10^-6, 7.16*10^-6, 
 9.76*10^-6, 0.0000116, 0.0000132, 0.0000152, "", 0.0000198, \
0.0000236, 0.0000257, 0.0000273, 0.0000287, 0.0000303, 0.0000294, \
0.0000278, 0.0000257, 0.0000239, 0.0000223, 0.00002, 0.0000184, \
0.0000163, 0.0000147, 0.0000129, 0.0000111, 9.1*10^-6, 7.39*10^-6, 
 5.42*10^-6, 3.53*10^-6, 2.1*10^-6, 
 6.21*10^-7, -1.29*10^-6, -2.77*10^-6, -3.92*10^-6, -6.09*10^-6, \
-7.55*10^-6, -7.55*10^-6, -0.0000111, -0.0000127, -0.0000146, \
-0.000016, -0.0000176, -0.0000193, -0.0000208, -0.0000223, \
-0.0000237, -0.0000252, -0.0000262, -0.0000262, -0.0000295, \
-0.0000305, -0.0000314, -0.0000327, -0.0000334, -0.0000344, \
-0.0000347, -0.0000353, -0.0000351, -0.0000349, -0.0000342, \
-0.0000326, "", -0.0000197, 5.36*10^-7, 
 7.15*10^-6, 0.0000117, 0.0000154, 0.0000177, 0.0000192, 0.0000209, \
0.0000214, 0.0000221, 0.0000225, 0.0000225, "", 0.0000229, 0.0000216, \
0.0000202, 0.0000194, 0.0000181, 0.0000171, 0.0000164, 0.000015, \
0.0000133, 0.0000122, 0.0000103, "", 5.69*10^-6, 
 2.4*10^-6, -7.92*10^-7, -2.57*10^-6, -3.8*10^-6, -5.73*10^-6, \
-7.57*10^-6, -9.38*10^-6, -0.0000111, -0.0000132, -0.0000148, \
-0.0000169, -0.0000183, -0.0000202, -0.0000218, -0.0000237, \
-0.0000253, -0.000027, -0.0000284, -0.0000306, -0.0000317};

BField = {"ï»¿10000.39258", 9926.71, 9753.31, 9553.6, 9353.67, 9153.66, \
8953.65, 8753.5, 8553.29, 8353.13, 8153.14, 7953.13, 7752.97, \
7552.86, 7353.25, 7153.36, 6953.29, 6753.62, 6553.47, 6353.31, \
6153.6, 5953.9, 5753.44, 5552.94, 5353.2, 5153.07, 4953.16, 4753.47, \
4553.01, 4353.3, 4153.54, 3953.03, 3752.89, 3552.98, 3353.06, \
3152.92, 2952.87, 2752.98, 2553.19, 2353.5, 2153.44, 1952.88, \
1752.74, 1552.62, 1352.12, 1152.4, 952.428, 752.302, 552.574, 352.34, \
-151.947, -556.781, -652.343, -847.615, -1047.75, -1247.28, -1447.3, \
-1647.63, -1847.38, -2047.14, -2247.47, -2447.92, -2647.83, -3154.02, \
-3559.45, -3653.04, -3846.57, -4047.03, -4247.54, -4446.88, -4646.19, \
-4846.62, -5047.05, -5247.21, -5447.34, -5647.21, -5847.3, -6047.42, \
-6247.12, -6446.82, -6646.87, -6846.88, -7046.54, -7246.27, -7446.34, \
-7646.43, -7846.78, -8046.89, -8246.18, -8446.21, -8951.32, -9356.78, \
-9451.92, -9647.21, -9846.9, -9973.31, -9926.79, -9753.78, -9554.16, \
-9354.13, -9154.55, -8954.45, -8753.93, -8554.08, -8354.06, -8153.96, \
-7954.24, -7754.61, -7554.58, -7354.49, -7154.46, -6954.43, -6754.8, \
-6555.13, -6354.76, -6154.64, -5955.32, -5755.24, -5554.82, -5354.72, \
-5154.56, -4954.41, -4754.38, -4554.55, -4354.45, -4154.76, -3954.64, \
-3754.54, -3555.01, -3355.44, -3155.4, -2954.92, -2755.14, -2555.44, \
-2355.56, -2155.53, -1955.45, -1755.26, -1555.16, -1355.13, -1155.11, \
-954.979, -755.29, -555.501, -51.2047, 353.059, 449.119, 645.156, \
844.884, 1044.6, 1245.1, 1445.18, 1644.92, 1845.08, 2045.35, 2245.77, \
2443.42, 2949.21, 3354.2, 3449.83, 3645.43, 3845.47, 4045.53, 4245.5, \
4445.27, 4644.96, 4845.01, 5045.58, 5245.87, 5750.52, 6154.81, \
6350.27, 6645.9, 6846.01, 7045.71, 7245.51, 7445.61, 7645.62, \
7845.34, 8045.41, 8245.76, 8445.88, 8645.97, 8845.68, 9045.82, \
9246.4, 9446.06, 9645.72, 9845.93, 9973.12};

datalist300K = Transpose@{BField, BMoment};
p1 = ListLinePlot[datalist300K, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];
BMomentDia = (-7.61*10^-9)*BField; (* I found the slope in excel and put it here but I want to automatically find the slope*)
data2 = Transpose@{BField, BMomentDia};
p2 = ListLinePlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
BMomentProcessed = BMoment - BMomentDia;
data3 = Transpose@{BField, BMomentProcessed};
p3 = ListLinePlot[data3,  PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> True, Joined -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Magnetic Field(Oe)", "Magnetization(emu)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10000, 10000}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, AspectRatio -> 3/5, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[.02]]]
```

[image]

Finally the plotted curve should look something like the one in red, but I also want to extrapolate the missing points in between, how do I go about?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the simplest way to have a smooth curve without breaks is making approximations with something like `BSpline`. First, let's remove the broken points:

```
mm = Position[BMoment, ""];
BMoment = Delete[BMoment, mm];
BField = Delete[BField, mm];
datalist300K = Transpose@{BField, BMoment};
```

Next, let's make a smooth curve:

```
sparam=3;
bf = BSplineFunction[datalist300K, SplineDegree -> 3,SplineClosed->True]; (*Curve with original data*)
bfs = BSplineFunction[MovingAverage[datalist300K,sparam], SplineDegree -> 3,SplineClosed->True]; (*Curve with smoothed data*)
Graphics[{
  Red, Line@Table[bfs[j], {j, 0, 1, 0.001}], 
  Blue, Line@Table[bf[j], {j, 0, 1, 0.001}],
  Point@datalist300K}, 
          ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

The argument of `bf` should be from 0 to 1 that corresponds to full trip along the hysteresis curve. Further, you can calculate from the `bf` or `bfs` anything like derivatives etc. And, of course, you can draw the curves with `ParametricPlot` instead of `Graphics`.

Answer (score 0):

The BMoment has some missing data and the first element of BField is garbled.  I manually adjusted BField.  With [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)and [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html), you delete the missing data from BMoment and then create an [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to fill in the missing data with a linear interpolation as shown with the code below.

```
BMoment = {-0.0000331, -0.0000354, -0.0000334, -0.0000315, \
-0.0000291, -0.0000269, -0.0000251, -0.0000234, -0.0000211, \
-0.0000189, -0.0000173, -0.0000152, -0.0000131, -0.0000114, \
-9.51*10^-6, -9.51*10^-6, -5.75*10^-6, -3.96*10^-6, -2.5*10^-6, \
-6.15*10^-7, 1.29*10^-6, 3.28*10^-6, 4.95*10^-6, 6.9*10^-6, 
   8.81*10^-6, 0.0000107, 0.000012, 0.0000139, 0.0000156, 0.0000172, 
   0.0000186, 0.0000199, 0.0000214, 0.0000229, 0.000024, 0.0000259, 
   0.0000271, 0.0000284, 0.0000294, 0.0000302, 0.0000314, 0.0000322, 
   0.0000331, 0.0000334, 0.0000332, 0.0000331, 0.0000321, 0.0000303, 
   0.0000276, "", 
   7.27*10^-6, -8.61*10^-6, -0.000013, -0.0000166, -0.0000189, \
-0.0000208, -0.0000221, -0.0000229, -0.0000236, -0.0000241, \
-0.0000242, -0.0000242, 
   "", -0.0000238, -0.0000224, -0.0000214, -0.0000205, -0.0000192, \
-0.000018, -0.0000168, -0.0000154, -0.0000137, -0.0000125, \
-0.0000109, -9.51*10^-6, -7.62*10^-6, -6.17*10^-6, -4.43*10^-6, \
-2.91*10^-6, -1.1*10^-6, 4.78*10^-7, 2.29*10^-6, 3.93*10^-6, 
   5.83*10^-6, 7.16*10^-6, 9.76*10^-6, 0.0000116, 0.0000132, 
   0.0000152, "", 0.0000198, 0.0000236, 0.0000257, 0.0000273, 
   0.0000287, 0.0000303, 0.0000294, 0.0000278, 0.0000257, 0.0000239, 
   0.0000223, 0.00002, 0.0000184, 0.0000163, 0.0000147, 0.0000129, 
   0.0000111, 9.1*10^-6, 7.39*10^-6, 5.42*10^-6, 3.53*10^-6, 
   2.1*10^-6, 
   6.21*10^-7, -1.29*10^-6, -2.77*10^-6, -3.92*10^-6, -6.09*10^-6, \
-7.55*10^-6, -7.55*10^-6, -0.0000111, -0.0000127, -0.0000146, \
-0.000016, -0.0000176, -0.0000193, -0.0000208, -0.0000223, \
-0.0000237, -0.0000252, -0.0000262, -0.0000262, -0.0000295, \
-0.0000305, -0.0000314, -0.0000327, -0.0000334, -0.0000344, \
-0.0000347, -0.0000353, -0.0000351, -0.0000349, -0.0000342, \
-0.0000326, "", -0.0000197, 5.36*10^-7, 7.15*10^-6, 0.0000117, 
   0.0000154, 0.0000177, 0.0000192, 0.0000209, 0.0000214, 0.0000221, 
   0.0000225, 0.0000225, "", 0.0000229, 0.0000216, 0.0000202, 
   0.0000194, 0.0000181, 0.0000171, 0.0000164, 0.000015, 0.0000133, 
   0.0000122, 0.0000103, "", 5.69*10^-6, 
   2.4*10^-6, -7.92*10^-7, -2.57*10^-6, -3.8*10^-6, -5.73*10^-6, \
-7.57*10^-6, -9.38*10^-6, -0.0000111, -0.0000132, -0.0000148, \
-0.0000169, -0.0000183, -0.0000202, -0.0000218, -0.0000237, \
-0.0000253, -0.000027, -0.0000284, -0.0000306, -0.0000317};

BField = {10000.39258, 9926.71, 9753.31, 9553.6, 9353.67, 9153.66, 
   8953.65, 8753.5, 8553.29, 8353.13, 8153.14, 7953.13, 7752.97, 
   7552.86, 7353.25, 7153.36, 6953.29, 6753.62, 6553.47, 6353.31, 
   6153.6, 5953.9, 5753.44, 5552.94, 5353.2, 5153.07, 4953.16, 
   4753.47, 4553.01, 4353.3, 4153.54, 3953.03, 3752.89, 3552.98, 
   3353.06, 3152.92, 2952.87, 2752.98, 2553.19, 2353.5, 2153.44, 
   1952.88, 1752.74, 1552.62, 1352.12, 1152.4, 952.428, 752.302, 
   552.574, 
   352.34, -151.947, -556.781, -652.343, -847.615, -1047.75, \
-1247.28, -1447.3, -1647.63, -1847.38, -2047.14, -2247.47, -2447.92, \
-2647.83, -3154.02, -3559.45, -3653.04, -3846.57, -4047.03, -4247.54, \
-4446.88, -4646.19, -4846.62, -5047.05, -5247.21, -5447.34, -5647.21, \
-5847.3, -6047.42, -6247.12, -6446.82, -6646.87, -6846.88, -7046.54, \
-7246.27, -7446.34, -7646.43, -7846.78, -8046.89, -8246.18, -8446.21, \
-8951.32, -9356.78, -9451.92, -9647.21, -9846.9, -9973.31, -9926.79, \
-9753.78, -9554.16, -9354.13, -9154.55, -8954.45, -8753.93, -8554.08, \
-8354.06, -8153.96, -7954.24, -7754.61, -7554.58, -7354.49, -7154.46, \
-6954.43, -6754.8, -6555.13, -6354.76, -6154.64, -5955.32, -5755.24, \
-5554.82, -5354.72, -5154.56, -4954.41, -4754.38, -4554.55, -4354.45, \
-4154.76, -3954.64, -3754.54, -3555.01, -3355.44, -3155.4, -2954.92, \
-2755.14, -2555.44, -2355.56, -2155.53, -1955.45, -1755.26, -1555.16, \
-1355.13, -1155.11, -954.979, -755.29, -555.501, -51.2047, 353.059, 
   449.119, 645.156, 844.884, 1044.6, 1245.1, 1445.18, 1644.92, 
   1845.08, 2045.35, 2245.77, 2443.42, 2949.21, 3354.2, 3449.83, 
   3645.43, 3845.47, 4045.53, 4245.5, 4445.27, 4644.96, 4845.01, 
   5045.58, 5245.87, 5750.52, 6154.81, 6350.27, 6645.9, 6846.01, 
   7045.71, 7245.51, 7445.61, 7645.62, 7845.34, 8045.41, 8245.76, 
   8445.88, 8645.97, 8845.68, 9045.82, 9246.4, 9446.06, 9645.72, 
   9845.93, 9973.12};
(* Make an index for parametric function *)
ts = First@Range[0, Dimensions@BMoment - 1];
(* Find positions of missing data in BMomnent *)
pos = Position[BMoment, _?NumericQ];
(* Create Linear Interpolation Functions *)
BMfn = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Extract[ts, pos], Extract[BMoment, pos]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
BFfn = Interpolation[Transpose[{ts, BField}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
ParametricPlot[{BFfn[u], BMfn[u]}, {u, 0, 
  First@(Dimensions@BMoment - 1)}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][u]]]
```

[image: Interpolated Data]

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, how do I extract the slope at high y-axis in both directions (positive and negative), take average and subtract from this raw data?

Comment: You can use `Last@FindMaximum[{BMfn[u], 50 <= u <= 150}, {u, 100}]` to show that  the maximum occurs at `u->95.5`.  Then you can differentiate the Interpolating functions on either side of 95.5 to get the slope.  For example, `(D[BMfn[u], u]/D[BFfn[u], u]) /. u -> 95` and `(D[BMfn[u], u]/D[BFfn[u], u]) /. u -> 96`.  You may want more samples because differentiating experimental data blows up the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fixed value supplied by Tim Laska, you could also do this:

```
originalData = Transpose[{BField, BMoment}];
originalGoodData = Sort@DeleteCases[originalData, {first_, second_} /; ! NumberQ[second]];
firstRangeEquation = Fit[Select[originalGoodData, -10000 <= #[[1]] <= -6000 &], {1, x}, x];
secondRangeEquation = Fit[Select[originalGoodData, 4000 <= #[[1]] <= 10000 &], {1, x}, x];
Show[{ListLinePlot[originalData], Plot[firstRangeEquation, {x, -10000, -2000}, PlotStyle -> Orange], Plot[secondRangeEquation, {x, 4000, 10000}, PlotStyle -> Purple]}]
```

The variables firstRangeEquation and secondRangeEquation provide the equations you want.